# AsseticBundle removed from all the Symfony's versions

Tags: bundle, assetic, symfony

I wanted to know why **AsseticBundle** has been removed from all the versions of Symfony.

I looked everywhere and I don't found any site talking about this news that began for some weeks.

Initially, I thought they deleted this Bundle because there is a security flaw that will take a few days to be repaired.

This Bundle is indisponsable for including javascript and css file type from an external folder and I wanted to be sure if this Bundle wille be replaced by an another in Symfony or I should add this Bundle manually.

Thanks

Comment: [Who said it has been removed?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html)

Comment: in this project they don't use it anymore (in the composer.)
[link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard)

Comment: that is just a skeleton application

Comment: well,
so I can add manually the AsseticBundle again ?

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: I want to follow the daily updates of this project "symfony-Standard" and since they removed the AsseticBundle I'm afraid that there would be a source of problems or I will be exposed to security flaws if I added this Bundle to my project

Comment: https://twitter.com/fabpot/status/648520881145253888

Comment: Thanks very much @Federico

Answer (score 4):

The AsseticBundle is not compatible/maintained with the new version of the framework (2.8/3.x).

See the tweet of Fabpot that asking: [Honest question: is #Assetic still relevant for #Symfony 3.0?](https://twitter.com/fabpot/status/648520881145253888?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

And the PR [remove AsseticBundle](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/860) (you can find good discussion about for and against the removal of Assetic).

Check also this great article on [Symfony and Asset Management](https://www.symfony.fi/entry/symfony-and-asset-management) that clarify and riassume all the discussion around.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Although Symfony does not support assetic from versions 2.8 upwards, you can still install it by running:

```
composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

and then enable the bundle in your AppKernel.php like so:

```
new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle()
```