# Unexpected "stylesheets" tag Symfony 3.0

Tags: css, twig, symfony

Just downloaded and created a new project using Symfony 3.0, but it is somehow accusing this error:

> Unexpected "stylesheets" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined near line 8) in base.html.twig at line 8.

According to the documentation, this is exactly how it is done:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/cdg/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Whats the matter?

Comment: Can you link to the docs your are following?  I don't recall the stylesheets tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096764/asseticbundle-removed-from-all-the-symfonys-versions

Answer (score 0):

The tag you refer is about AsseticBundle that  was removed in the new version of the framework.

See the tweet of Fabpot that asking: [Honest question: is #Assetic still relevant for #Symfony 3.0?](https://twitter.com/fabpot/status/648520881145253888?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

And the PR [remove AsseticBundle](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/860) (you can find good discussion about for and against the removal of Assetic).

Check also this great article on [Symfony and Asset Management](https://www.symfony.fi/entry/symfony-and-asset-management) that clarify and riassume all the discussion around.

Hope this help